# android studio debug: can not resolve symbols in dependency jar

Tags: android-studio, debugging

Android studio debug:

An android lib project that uses a java library jar which has

```
/package/Foo.java
/package/Bar.java
```

In the android library project code:

```
 Bar.someMethod(...)
```

The Bar class can not be resolved. So I can not step into the class. Other classes in the dependency jar can be resolved without problems.

Tried the followings, but no luck.

```
1. Invalidate and Restart
2. Delete .idea and *.iml files
3. close project and re-open
4. gradle clean and rebuild
```

Answer (score 0):

One posible case for that error can be that this 'Bar class' be referenced in another library first and so the main project taking the first instance of 'Bar class' instead of 'Bar class' from dependency what you're try to debugging.
This response can be apply to your problem or not, if not you can give more details please.
I hope its help you.